# Convert list into string in robot framework

Tags: python-2.7, robotframework

I want to convert given list into `[u'', u'src', u'kirti', u'lib', u'auto']` string using robot framework `/src/kirti/lib/auto/`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! When you created your account here, it was suggested you take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the [help center pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help) in order to familiarize yourself with the site. Specific pages that you should read include [How Do I Ask a Good Question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please take these introductory steps and then edit your post accordingly.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/robotframework-users/CJ0LihQvcoQ  This may be exactly what you need

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that the robot list `@{data}` contains the information you want to join, you can use `evaluate` along with robot's special syntax for variables to call the python `join` method:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Example
    @{data}=  create list  ${empty}  src  kirti  lib  auto
    ${path}=  Evaluate  "/".join($data)
    should be equal  ${path}  /src/kirti/lib/auto
```